# Socratic badge without 100 questions

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

Recently I earned [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic?userid=339911) and click on [Others with this badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) link. I noticed that [@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) also have this badge. But he has only [99 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=4) now, and two of them have negative score.

More over according to results of [this script](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges#resultSets) separate days when user has asked questions with positive score is 92 for @Shog9:

> [image: 92]

To be honest I don't really trust script due to it says that I have N = 124, but I got Socratic badge only today.

One possible explanation is that Shog9 have deleted at least 3 questions with positive score. Is it true?

Comment: this is plausible. He could have gotten the badge then cleared out obsolete stuff.

Comment: Full stats: I've asked 119 questions here; 113 of them score 1 or more, but 16 of those are deleted (many were migrated to MSO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is not rare that old questions that become obsolete are being deleted, to prevent confusion.

For example, [What is the meaning of CHAOS? Is it related to the PSI (Ψ) character?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-%CE%A8-character) was posted by Joel Spolsky and deleted after about a year, when the CHAOS project has ended and the question served no purpose anymore. All that while it got almost 100 upvotes.

Another option is questions that got migrated over to MSO at some point, which is equivalent for deleting, as we won't see them on the user's profile. For example [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) was migrated to MSO.

So Shog got questions that were well received then at some point deleted or migrated, hence not visible in his profile. No bug, and nothing really odd here.

Comment: Turns out that migrated post calculated twice in badge statistics: once for original site, then for target site. This is not very fair.

Comment: @alexolut why not fair?? Badges are NEVER revoked, even when post is deleted. On the source site, it doesn't matter how the question was deleted, i.e. if by OP, moderator, or migration. **Badges are not revoked, and should not be**.

Comment: If post is deleted user still get badge for his efforts. But for migrated one he got double prize for same efforts.

Comment: @alexolut that's also true for upvotes which are preserved. So what? Still can't see anything unfair here. Migration isn't something that is done lightly, it's pretty rare, and OP don't do it on purpose, it's not like they try to game the system.

Comment: [Okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y98ql.jpg)